# Cambiar index bucle python

Tags: python

Mi problema es modificar el valor de k. Es decir cuando llamo a la función funmeta, esta me devuelve una posición que quiero que adquiera k y vuelva a empezar el bucle de arriba por esa posición. Conforme está en el código, no se modifica.

```
for k,i in enumerate(lista):
        print(k)
        print(i.m)
        valor = input("Introduce el valor de m" + i.m)
        index = funmeta(lista, i.m, valor)
        if(index!=0):
            k = index
        k = index
        print(k)
        print(i.m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En estos casos lo más sencillo es cambiar el ciclo `for` por un `while`, de forma que la variable de control del `while` es el indice en si y puede ser modificada sin problemas desde dentro del propio ciclo.

Dado que no se que hace tu función `funmeta()` o qué es `i.m`, te dejo una implementación con la misma idea, cambiar el índice de iteración dentro del propio ciclo a voluntad al recorrer una lista.

En este ejemplo puedes cambiar el índice mediante el retorno de la función `getIndx` que usa un `input`, si introduces un índice válido la función retorna este indice y el bucle se 'reinicia' por esa posición de la lista, si se introduce otra cosa la función retorna -1 y el ciclo continua normalmente:

```python3
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def getIndx(lista):
    try:
        index = int(input("Introduce el nuevo indice, entre 0 y {0} o otra si desea continuar el ciclo: ".format(len(lista)-1)))
        if index in range(0, len(lista)):
            return index
    except:
        return -1

#A partir de aquí el código es el sustituto de tu for

k = 0
while k < len(lista):
    v = lista[k]
    print('Indice:', k, 'Valor:', lista[k])
    k+=1

    index = getIndx(lista)

    if index >= 0:
        k = index
```

Si tienes problemas para adaptarlo a tu código edita la pregunta añadiendo el código mínimo para poder reproducir tu programa.